# Overriding equals()

Tags: java, overriding

When running this part of the code, why do I get 'O' instead of 'P'?

```
class Pop{
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o){
            System.out.print("O");
            return false;
        }
        public boolean equals(Pop p){
            System.out.print("P");
            return false;
        }
        public static void main (String[] args) 
        {
            Pop p1 = new Pop();
            Object o = p1;
            o.equals(p1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because over*load* resolution -- choosing among methods based on argument types -- is performed at compile time, based on the declared types of the expressions designating the target object and method arguments.  Only over*ride* resolution -- choosing among methods of a given signature based on the type of the object on which it is invoked -- happens dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Jashua Bloch in his book _Effective Java_, deals with exactly this situation.

Comment: [You can find the explanation in the answer below ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109231/method-overload-resolution-in-java)

Comment: Because you didn't research what `override` is and *when* it happens?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Do you mean the _equals_ method that get a Pop as the parameter is actually an _overload_, not an _override_?

Comment: Yes, @Caspar.  `Pop.equals(Pop)` has the same name as another method belonging to class `Pop`, but different parameters.  That is an overload.  Contrast with `Pop.equals(Object)`, which has the same name and parameter list as an inherited method; this is an override of the inherited method.  Note, too, that even if `Pop` did not override `equals(Object)`, `Pop.equals(Pop)` would still be an overload of the version inherited from `Object`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger All right, I fully understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what happens when you code `o.equals(p1)`:

1. When Java compiles this, it looks at the type of `o`, and it sees that it is `Object`, because that's what you declared it to be.  It won't know that it's a `Pop`.  As far as the compiler is concerned, it could be an object of *any* type.  (You can tell by looking at the previous code that it will be a `Pop`, but the compiler doesn't do that kind of analysis.)
2. The Java compiler looks at the `Object` class for a matching definition of `equals`.  There's only one definition of `equals`, and it matches (that is, the argument list is compatible with the definition).  So the Java bytecode is created to say, "We're calling the method `equals` defined in `Object`."
3. At run time, when the call is made, it calls the method `equals` defined in `Object`, like the bytecode says.  Any time Java makes a call, though, it will use an overriding call if there is one.  So it looks at the actual class, `Pop`, and sees whether `Pop` (or any other superclass between `Object` and `Pop`, but there isn't one here) overrides that method in `Object`.  The first method in `Pop` does override it, so that's the one that's executed, and `"O"` gets printed.  The second `equals` method isn't looked at at all, since it doesn't override the `equals` in `Object`.

I don't know what mechanism the compiler uses for storing override information.  But in another compiler for a different language that I've worked with, methods get indexes, or "slot" numbers, in a vector.  When `Object` is defined, its methods get unique slots; the slot for `equals` might be, say, 7.  So the 7th entry in the vector would be the address of `equals`.  When `Pop` is defined, since the first `equals` overrides the one in `Object`, it would also get slot 7.  The second `equals` doesn't override anything, so it gets a new slot number, maybe 18.  So there would be a vector where index 7 contains the address of the first `equals` in `Pop`, and index 18 contains the address of the second one.  Now, when the code calls `equals` in `Object`, the code says something like "call whatever method is in slot 7".  For a `Pop` object, the method in slot 7 will be the first `equals`, which prints `"O"`.  But it never looks at slot 18.  I doubt that Java operates exactly in this way, but the effect is similar.  Basically, there's some ID that gets looked up, and the method for that ID is called; Java does not, at run time, search for another method defined in the class that might get called.

**MORE:** If you really want the behavior where it prints `"P"` if its argument is a `Pop`, you can do it like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o instanceof Pop) {
            return equals((Pop)o);  
            // this equals will be the one below, because of overload resolution
        }
        System.out.print("O");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It really helps a lot.