# Is a List<T> considered as an Object, Collection or anything else - Java

Tags: java

I have a class B that contains these four methods:

```
public class B {

public void f(int x) {
    System.out.println("1");
}

public void f(Object x) {
    System.out.println("2");
}

public void f(List x) {
    System.out.println("3");
}
public void f(Collection x){
    System.out.println("4");
}
```

and in the main I have these commands:

```
B o = new B();
    Integer n = new Integer(3);
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
    Collection<Integer> m = new ArrayList<>();
    o.f(3);
    o.f(n);
    o.f(l);
    o.f(m);
```

The result will be:
1
2
3
4

why does "3" considered as int while Integer(3) concidered as Object?
And why List or Collection isn't considered as Object?

Comment: well one is a primitive type and the other is an object.

Comment: Because 3 is primitive int. While Integer(3) is a an object of wrapper type of int .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method overload resolution in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109231/method-overload-resolution-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's picking the most specific version of the method at compile time.

`Integer` is being considered an `Object` because *it is* an `Object` (it inherits from `Object`):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

`Collection` and `List` would be considered an `Object` as well if you didn't have the more specific versions of the methods.

But since you also overloaded the method for `Collection` and `List`, those are used.

Comment: Thank you, answered my question! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here, Ill just look at the List, Collection, Object since the Integer int is answered elsewhere.

The most specified method is used.

So a List inherits from Collection and they are both Object. That makes List  more specific so when you pass the List, it chooses the method that takes List as an argument. Even though the List could be passed to the Object or Collection method. You can achieve the same effect with a cast.

```
o.f(((Object)l));
```

Will result in a 2.