# Java equals confusion

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have 2 equals method in the circle class,

```
public boolean equals(Object obj);
public boolean equals(Circle circle);
```

And I do this:

```
Circle c1 = new Circle(new Point(0, 0), 10);
Circle c2 = new Circle(new Point(0, 0), 10);
Object o1 = c1;
Object o2 = c2;
```

For `o1.equals(c1);` why does it call the `equals(Object obj)` instead of `equals(Circle circle)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method overload resolution in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109231/method-overload-resolution-in-java)

Comment: "Why"? Because it's specified that way. If you want to know why they specified it that way, you'd have to ask somebody from Sun Microsystems in the early 1990es.

Comment: You should not have an equals(Circle) method. It can create confusion. And please don't forget to override hashCode() also.

Comment: I love the ambiguity of the title of your question :D

Answer (score 3):

The declared type decide what kinds of methods you can call, the real type decide what implementationi to use.
If you call `o1.equals(c1)`, because the decalred type is `Object`,the compiler will find method in `Object` to use which is `equals(Object obj)`.
if you call `c2.equals(c1)`, this time the declared type is `Circle`, the compiler will find that `equals(Circle)` is better than `equals(Object)` with java's method overload resolution mechanism.

In fact you can view the two equals method as two totally different method which happens to have same name.

Answer (score 0):

This exact scenario is described in Effective Java. From page 49 of the third edition,

> **Don’t substitute another type for Object in the equals declaration.** It is not uncommon for a programmer to write an equals method that looks like this and then spend hours puzzling over why it doesn’t work properly:

```
// Broken - parameter type must be Object!
public boolean equals(MyClass o) {
    ...
}
```

> The problem is that this method does not *override* `Object.equals`, whose argument is of type `Object`, but *overloads* it instead. It is unacceptable to provide such a “strongly typed” `equals` method even in addition to the normal one, because it can cause `Override` annotations in subclasses to generate false positives and provide a false sense of security.